# Calculate the number of characters a particular string can be shown in a uilabel

Tags: swift, uilabel, width, string-length

Does anyone know how to calculate the number of characters a particular string can be shown in a uilabel in swift 3.1?

Comment: label.text?.characters.count

Comment: Thanks but that gets the length of the string but the string could be larger than what would fit in the uilabel

Comment: use sizetofit()

Comment: Will that work if I want to add a drop down arrow character at the end of the visible string so that when the user taps on the uilabel it will expand to show the full string?

Comment: This would depend on the string you are displaying. The letter `i` would take up less space then `m` for example (unless you choose a monospace font)

Comment: you can use constraints for that scenario

Comment: I think I am just to make the ui simpler and use a uilabel which does can show all the text at once.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -3):

```
myLabel.text = "Hello"
var num = myLabel.text?.characters.count // num = 5
```